# How do I keep a persistent .onion address after rebooting for my hidden service on OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt, tor

I'm running OpenWrt 18.06.1 on a [GL.iNet GL-USB150](https://www.gl-inet.com/products/gl-usb150/)([WikiDev](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/GL.iNet_GL-USB150)).  I have an SSH server running on the tor network.
This is the contents of my `/etc/tor/torrc`

```
Log notice syslog
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
User tor
```

Each time I reboot my private key and .onion address changes, which I see in these files:

```
/var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/hostname
/var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/private_key
```

How do I make my onion address persistent?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `tor` "DataDirectory" and "HiddenServiceDir" somewhere under `/etc/tor/` should make them persist across reboots.

So, just change the 2 paths in your `/etc/tor/torrc` to not point onto `var` anymore.